# Creating a URL & setting Vue.js Vuex state from its parameters

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuex

I have a SPA built in Vue.js that lets the user input several values to create something like a recipe.  All these values are stored in Vuex state.  I would like to be able to create a URL using the state values that the user entered so that another user can load the app with those values already entered.  Essentially I want to allow users to share the recipes they created in my app by sharing a URL.

I'm imagining a "share" button which will copy the created URL to the user's clipboard which they can then post on social media or whatever.  Then when someone visits the link, they will go to my app and the vuex state values will automatically be updated to the parameter values found in the URL.

What is the best way to achieve this functionality?  Is this something that is possible with `vue-router`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `$route.query` property provided by `vue-router`.

Pass in a parameters through your URL like `http://example.com/#/?amount=10` and access them with `this.$route.query.amount`.

Update your `vuex` store in the main component's `mounted()` method.

[Official Documentation for the Route object](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/route-object.html)

Comment: What if the whole vuex state needs to be stored, like 50+ variables and not just strings? And you wanted to have a unique hash-ID based on that, for example yourapp.com/#/?id=IAF3D0K. How would you approach it

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly the vue-router should do exactly that.

have a look at the documentation where they send the user id. You can pass as many parameters as you like.

https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html

note: you may consider rebuilding application paths using the router.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll take a look at this.  I know very little about vue-router right now but I had a hunch that it might be part of the answer.  My application actually has no paths other than the root path.  It's simply a one page recipe calculator.  So the only thing I'll need vue-router for is this, assuming vue-router can do it.  I guess I'll find out after I read more of the documentation.

Comment: So I read more about `vue-router` and learned about the `$router.query` property.  This should do the trick.

I can pass in a parameter like `http://example.com/#/?amount=10` and use `this.$route.query.amount` to retrieve the values during the mounting phase and update the `vuex` store.